# How do I iterate over a node's child nodes after selecting it with selectSingleNode

Tags: xml, vba, msxml

I am trying to select a single node from an XML document with `selectSingleNode()` and then use `selectNodes` on that node to further select child items of that node:

```
option explicit

sub main() ' {

   dim doc as new MSXML2.DOMDocument

   doc.loadXML(                                                                                     _
     "<items>"                                                                                    & _
     "  <item id='1000'><name val='ABC'/><name val='DEF'/><name val='GHI'/><foo>xxx</foo></item>" & _
     "  <item id='1001'><name val='JKL'/><name val='MNO'/><name val='PQR'/><bar>yyy</bar></item>" & _
     "  <item id='1002'><name val='STU'/><name val='VWX'/><name val='YZ.'/><baz>zzz</baz></item>" & _
     "</items>")

    dim item as msxml2.IXMLDOMElement
    set item = doc.selectSingleNode("//item[@id='1002']")

    dim names as msxml2.IXMLDOMSelection
    set names = item.selectNodes("//name")

    dim name as msxml2.IXMLDOMElement
    for each name in names
        debug.print(name.getAttribute("val"))
    next name

end sub ' }
```

I have expected this piece of code to print the Attribute values `STU`, `VWX` and `YZ.`. However, when running it, it prints each `<name>`'s `val` value.

Apparently, `selectNodes()` selects all nodes from the root document.

I don't understand why this is and how I can get the *real* child nodes of a previously selected node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change**

```
Set names = item.selectNodes("//name")
```

**To**

```
Set names = item.SelectNodes("name")
```

Comment: I just discovered that I can also use the more explicit, imho, variant `set names = item.selectNodes("./nam")`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to iterate over a selection returned by the xpath shown below. It is essentially a nodeset containing attribute nodes.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub main()
   Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

   doc.LoadXML ( _
     "<items>" & _
     "  <item id='1000'><name val='ABC'/><name val='DEF'/><name val='GHI'/><foo>xxx</foo></item>" & _
     "  <item id='1001'><name val='JKL'/><name val='MNO'/><name val='PQR'/><bar>yyy</bar></item>" & _
     "  <item id='1002'><name val='STU'/><name val='VWX'/><name val='YZ.'/><baz>zzz</baz></item>" & _
     "</items>")

    Dim items As IXMLDOMSelection, item As Object
    Set items = doc.SelectNodes("//*[@id='1002']/name/@*") 'all attribs. Or, //*[@id='1002']/name/@val for only val attributes
    For Each item In items
        Debug.Print item.text
    Next
End Sub
```

---

If you want a more verbose method

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub main()
    Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    doc.LoadXML ( _
                "<items>" & _
                "  <item id='1000'><name val='ABC'/><name val='DEF'/><name val='GHI'/><foo>xxx</foo></item>" & _
                "  <item id='1001'><name val='JKL'/><name val='MNO'/><name val='PQR'/><bar>yyy</bar></item>" & _
                "  <item id='1002'><name val='STU'/><name val='VWX'/><name val='YZ.'/><baz>zzz</baz></item>" & _
                "</items>")

    Dim item As Object, attrib As Object, child As Object
    Set item = doc.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='1002']")

    For Each child In item.ChildNodes
        For Each attrib In child.Attributes
            If attrib.name = "val" Then Debug.Print attrib.name, attrib.text
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

You could even mess around with:

```
For Each child In item.ChildNodes
    If child.BaseName = "name" And child.getAttribute("val") <> vbNullString Then Debug.Print child.getAttribute("val")
Next
```